# k8s check wait for pod existence

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In K8s job file declared in yaml (with helm), I need that the job will run only whether the pod database exists and ready.

For the readiness, it works fine, since I added the following:

```
initContainers
    - name: wait-mysql-ready
      image: "bitnami//kubectl:latest"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - kubectl
      args:
        - wait
        - pod/mysql-pod
        - --for=condition=ready
        - --timeout=120s
```

It works fine, but I need the job to run once (without duplications, and with long time period till it ends).

The job doesn't as usual run once, and it's name, when running `kubectl get pods` is `<jobname-hash>`

If it doesn't run once, at a the last attempt it will succeed (because the pod isn't created yet). Other attempt may failed.

So I added the following lines in main spec:

```
spec:
  parallelism: 1 
  completions: 1
  backoffLimit: 0
```

and in init container section (befor the previous one), I have added:

```
initContainers
  - name: wait-mysql-exist-pod
    image: "bitnami/kubectl:latest"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command:
      - /bin/sh
    args:
      - -c
      - "while !(kubectl get pod mysql-pod); do echo 'Waiting for mysql pod to be existed...'; sleep 5; done"
```

(I could not find other good syntax for `!` - for multiline string. I would be glade knowing how).

Also need another job to wait for the current job.

How can I create a job that run once, and check in the job that the pod exists before checking the ready state?

Comment: When/at what moment job should be run? When pod is supposed to be created? I can think of using for example a [`post-install`](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks) helm hook to do everything once all resources are created with `--wait` flag

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [this script](https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for) as init-container to wait for other resources.

Comment: That's seem too complicated solution for a simple problem. As my post, I indeed using "kubectl wait for", but it waits for pod to be ready,. If it not exist at all, I may need something else, since kubectl wait is waiting for state after the pod exists, but what I need to check for its exsistence. BTW, I cannot load a non-standatd k8s package. The company I work uses the standards only.